# How to refer to Presentation Variable in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, variables, obiee

I'm on OBIEE 11g.  I am trying to create a printer-friendly dashboard that shows in the footer how the dashboard was prompted on each page.  I don't want to use the filter object because it is query specific and I have multiple queries per dashboard.

I've assigned all prompts with a presentation variable and I've referred to the presentation variables in the footer.  I now am almost where I want to be.  I would now just like to use javascript logic (supported in footer section) so that all blank prompts are filtered out.

Is it possible to refer to a presentation variable in JS?  If so, how should I build the syntax?

UPDATE: The use of JS was not needed.  There is a feature on the syntax of the Presentation Variable code that allows you to enter how you display nulls.  The basic code format is this: @{var_name}.  Adding an extra set of curly brackets activates the ability to modify the default display.  @{var_name}{} displays the blank that I was looking for instead of the variable name I had before.

Answer (score 1):

The use of JS was not needed. There is a feature on the syntax of the Presentation Variable code that allows you to enter how you display nulls. The basic code format is this: @{var_name}. Adding an extra set of curly brackets activates the ability to modify the default display. @{var_name}{} displays the blank that I was looking for instead of the variable name I had before.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you can reference a presentation variable from JS, and I think that's still an interesting question.

However, a more scalable/supportable solution might be to use the built in functionality – which I think could meet your requirement.

You could either make a new Analysis and drop in as many columns as you have presentation variables, and change the column formula for each in turn to reference your presentation variables. I'm not sure how you'd display that though.

Alternatively, I would probably do it in a Narrative view, where you can reference the presentation variables directly and possibly format it a little better.

Inspiration from [Nico Gerard](http://gerardnico.com/wiki/dat/obiee/presentation_variable_use).